# Complexity of a variant of Subset Sum problem

Tags: complexity-theory, subset-sum

This is the variant of SSP: Given $n$ positive integer points $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ which are all at most $n$, does there exist a subset $\{a_i\}_{i \in P}$, such that its summation is exactly $n+1$?

My question is, for general $n$, is this problem NP-hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is polynomial-time solvable using a reduction to [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Take a knapsack of size $W = n+1$. Take $n$ items of size $a_i$ and value $a_i$. The maximum value obtained is $n+1$ if and only if there exists a subset of items that sum to $n+1$.

The 0-1 knapsack problem can be solved in time $O(n \cdot W)$ using dynamic programming. Therefore, the running time of the algorithm here is $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

No (unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$), the problem is in $\mathsf{P}$. The following is polynomial-time dynamic programming algorithm.

For $i=0,\dots,n$ and $j=0, \dots, n+1$ let $S[i,j]$ be true iff there exists a subset of $\{a_1, \dots, a_i\}$ whose elements sum up to $j$.
We trivially have that $S[i,0]$ is true for all $i$, while $S[0,j]$ if false for all $j>0$. Moreover, for $i,j>0$ we have:
$$
S[i,j]=
\begin{cases}
S[i-1,j] & \mbox{if } a_i > j \\
S[i-1,j] \vee S[i-1, j-a_i] & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

The instance admits a solution if and only if $S[n, n+1]$ is true.

Comment: Wont this count a certain element more than once? For example, given the singe integer $1$, there is no way to get a subset of sum $n+1=2$, since the only two subsets have sum $1$ or $0$. Your algorithm, will give $S[0]=S[1]=S[2]=true$. In general, your algorithm will always output $true$ if $1$ is in the input, which doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: @nirshahar. Right! I fixed my answer.

Comment: Sounds correct now! :)